# Why is it when I enter in an operation in to VBA Excel, VBA removes the operator sign?

Tags: vba, excel

I will write something like:

```
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Counter = 0
a = 1
Counter-a
```

But, then VBA appends it to this:

```
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Counter = 0
a = 1
Counter a '<---------------This change is what I am confused about
```

This is my full code so far:

```
Private Sub SpinButtonM_SpinDown()
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim a As Integer
a = 1
Counter a
UserForm2.Month.Caption = Counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `Counter = Counter - a` or `Counter -= a` ?

Comment: Thanks for all the fast replies. Yes I was trying to decrement Counter to move up and down an array to display different months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to decrement like this:

```
Counter = Counter - a
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to subtract variable `a` from variable `Counter` then you need to store the **result** of that subtraction somewhere. So you might want to introduce another variable like

```
Dim result as Integer
...
result = Counter - a
msgbox(result)
```

Or maybe you want to decrease the `Counter` variable by `a`, then you need

`Counter = Counter - a`